# Show that $\sqrt{-2}$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A =  \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]= \{a+b\sqrt{-2} \ : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that $\sqrt{-2}$ is an irreducible element of $A$.

Here I considered the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{-2})=a^2+2b^2$. I don't know if I can use this strategy to conclude, but this is what I did :

Suppose that $\sqrt{-2}$ is reductible, i.e. $\sqrt{-2}=(a+b \sqrt{-2})(c + b \sqrt{-2})$. So $N(\sqrt{-2})=N((a+b \sqrt{-2})(c + b \sqrt{-2}))=N(a+b \sqrt{-2}) N(c + b \sqrt{-2})) = 2$. Since $2$ is a prime number, then $\sqrt{-2}$ is irreductible.

Is anyone could tell me if I am right? Otherwise, could you give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199450/irreducible-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt-3) for the argument. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101537/irreducible-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt-2-and-is-it-a-euclidean-domain).

Comment: I find your argument exemplary. That is, not only correct, but efficient and clear.

Comment: I think it is fine if it is clear that $\;Nw=1\iff w\;$ is a unit in the ring, so that the only decomposition possible for $\;\sqrt{-2}\;$ is a trivial one.